# Text fade not returning after hovering over animated text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on our website we have a logo header text with other text next to it that will fade out periodically and change text.

The issue is that as soon as the logo is hovered over the text fade will not generate the next stage of text and not come back even when the logo is no longer being hovered over.

How do I stop the text from disappearing and not returning?

The code for this is

```
 //FADER TEXT
        $('#headerFader').carousel({
            interval: 2500,
            pause: false
        });

        //BACK HOME TEXT
       $('#headerText').hover(
           function(){
               $(this).find("h1#masterHeader").animate({opacity:0}, 0, function(){
                   $(this).css("display", "none");
                   $('#headerText').find("h1#takemeback").css("display", "block");
                   $('#headerText').find("h1#takemeback").animate({opacity:1,});
               });
           },
           function(){
               $(this).find("h1#takemeback").animate({opacity:0}, 0, function(){
                   $(this).css("display", "none");
                   $('#headerText').find("h1#masterHeader").css("display", "block");
                   $('#headerText').find("h1#masterHeader").animate({opacity:1,});
               });
           }
       );
```

to fix this I duplicated the headerfader in the second function like this

```
function(){
       $(this).find("h1#takemeback").animate({opacity:0}, 0, function(){
           $(this).css("display", "none");
           $('#headerText').find("h1#masterHeader").css("display", "block");
           $('#headerText').find("h1#masterHeader").animate({opacity:1,});
           //FADER TEXT
            $('#headerFader').carousel({
                interval: 2500,
                pause: false
            });

       });
   }
```

is there a more elegant way of doing this instead of repeating the headerfader?

Comment: Did you get an error when running?

Comment: Hi, no errors. The fade out text just disappears

Comment: Can you create a simple example of this on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I have made http://jsfiddle.net/yzzu3hc7/ and there does not seem to be any issues. You shouldn't need the `h1` before the ID since ID should be unique. Post your html please

Comment: I added the $('#headerFader').carousel({
                        interval: 2500,
                        pause: false
                    });

to the second second function as well, is there a more elegant way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a trailing comma in your animate functions,

```
$('#headerText').find("h1#takemeback").animate({opacity:1,});
```

Try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: For both hover functions

Comment: I noticed that your duration for the animate functions is 0, if you don't care for the transitions, why not just flat out set the styles on hove?

Comment: like this kind of thing:     $('#headerText').hover(
           function(){
               $(this).find("h1#masterHeader").css("display", "none");
               $(this).find("h1#takemeback").css("display", "");               
           },
           function(){
              $(this).find("h1#masterHeader").css("display", "");
               $(this).find("h1#takemeback").css("display", "none");    
           }
       );

Comment: Instead of using `.css()` for showing/hiding, you can just use `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: This is code I've inherited from someone else, this is just a bug I've been tasked with looking at.  I'll give the above suggestions an attempt.

Comment: I fixed it by adding the headerfader to the takemeback function as well. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?